# Member variable detection type trait

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits

Is it possible to define a type trait in C++ that detects whether a class has any member variables at all? I want to be able to check if a type is a class and has no member variables.

Comment: [`std::is_empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty), approximately

Comment: I looked at the type_traits header, but must have missed that one. Thanks

Comment: @dyp: I think that only checks for non-static data members. It's harder to check for absence of static members I think.

Comment: If `T` is polymorphic, is using `sizeof(T) == sizeof(EmptyPolymorphicClass)` for determining whether `T` has any member variables a good idea?

Comment: @felix I'd guess that this should work fine on sane platforms, but I think an insane implementation could use a vptr plus a couple of byte for polymorphism. Say the vptr needs 8 byte alignment, and the C++ for DS9K compiler adds the vptr plus 3 byte for polymorphism. Because arrays are contiguous, the class would have 5 padding bytes after the polymorphism stuff (to align the next array element). The compiler could store some data members within those 5 padding bytes, I'd say.